# Creating dev/Staging enviroment in Azure

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I am trying to create a deployment plan for my web application in Azure which can support 2 environments (Dev/Staging). Basically, I want the code checked in by developers to be deployed to the Dev machine end of the day. And then the latest Dev changes to be merged with staging branch and if no merge conflict happened a new publish goes to staging machine. Can anyone help me where to start and what feature in azure i can use to server this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Azure Devops to trigger scheduled builds (at the end of the day) to perform the routine you are describing. you could also use releases and trigger them automatically from the builds that happen on a schedule.

You would also need to deploy vsts agents on the machines or allow for vsts agents to somehow talk to the machines to upload code to them

Comment: Is that possible for web apps services or could be only done when using VMs ?

Comment: possible for both, for webapps you can do that natively and for vms you would need to install agents on vms or somehow invent a way to deliver code to the vms

Comment: The only thing i have heard so far for creating environments for web apps is Azure is just through slots? is there any thing else? I don't think slots is going to help me in my scenario coz i don't want to swap between them!?

Comment: just create several webapps